# how to add interlaced color bands in d3 v4 vertically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459101/how-to-add-laced-color-band-in-d3-js), I would like to achieve the same interlaced color bands in d3 v4 or v5 which are vertical which would look similar to following image.

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoF3v.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us some example of what you tried? What error you saw?

Answer (score 0):

Just Now I tried with the following code and its working, anyhow thanks.

```js
// To apply interlaced color bands in background
    const xval = [];
    d3.selectAll('.x.axis>g>text').each(function (d) { xval.push(d); });

    const bands = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'instBands');

    bands.selectAll('rect').data(xval).enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) { return x0(d); }).attr('y', 0)  // x0 is nothing but 
    /* const x0 = d3.scaleBand()
       .rangeRound([0, (this.width - margin.left - margin.right - 80)])
     .padding(0.1); */
    .attr('height', (this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom)) // height of svg
    .attr('width', (this.width - margin.left - margin.right - 80) / xval.length) // width of svg
    .style('fill-opacity', function(d, i) {
      if (i === 0) {
        return 0.025;
      }
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        return 0.025;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: since when is `0%2 != 0`? why create rects with opacity of 0? filter `xval` before adding the rects. why not use `xScale.domain()` instead of getting the `text` values?

Comment: rects with opacity 0 is to create white band and 0.025 for a bit colored band. I am making use of x0.domain but not included in above code why because it is just a snippet. I will upload the whole working code soon.

Comment: why draw something you will **never** see?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.